# NEAT multiple genomes at once in one instance of pygame

Tags: python, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network, neat

I am using neat for an RNN to train in flappy bird done with `pygame`.

Does anyone have a clue on how I can do that?

```
neat.ParallelEvaluator(4, eval_genome)
```

just opens four windows from `pygame`.

I want to do something similar to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtRA6tqgJBc).

I was able to recreate some of the code here: [link to GitHub](https://github.com/GianottiGustavo/neat-flappy/blob/master/FlapPyBio-master/flappy_train.py) , but after my whole population dies I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Philipp/PycharmProjects/BallBounce/Main.py", line 64, in <module>
    winner = pop.run(eval_genomes, 50)
  File "C:\Users\Philipp\PycharmProjects\BallBounce\venv\lib\site-packages\neat\population.py", line 89, in run
    fitness_function(list(iteritems(self.population)), self.config)
  File "C:/Users/Philipp/PycharmProjects/BallBounce/Main.py", line 34, in eval_genomes
    genoinf,scoreinf = Game.game(genomes,config,SCORE) #game Returns fitness
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue myself.

Had a silly `print()` in my code that bascilly doubles the generations for each timeframe

like:

```
print(gen.append(bird.gen))
```